# Outlook addin not popping in the ribbon

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have created my first addin using `yo`.
npm serve works fine, because I can access `https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html`, but I cannot see the addin in the outlook ribbon.

I have the standard manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>fa30fddd-aba2-460b-a326-fc46165e5432</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="My Office Add-in"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost"/>
    </Hosts>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                  <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a task pane."/>
          <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

webpack execution console:

```bash
You already have trusted access to https://localhost.
Certificate: C:\Users\adminuser\.office-addin-dev-certs\localhost.crt
Key: C:\Users\adminuser\.office-addin-dev-certs\localhost.key
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: https://localhost:3000/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): https://10.0.0.4:3000/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'C:\temp\My Office Add-in\public' directory
assets by path assets/*.png 26.9 KiB
  asset assets/logo-filled.png 11.6 KiB [emitted] [from: assets/logo-filled.png] [copied]
  asset assets/icon-80.png 4.72 KiB [emitted] [from: assets/icon-80.png] [copied]
  asset assets/icon-128.png 4.58 KiB [emitted] [from: assets/icon-128.png] [copied]
  asset assets/icon-32.png 2.33 KiB [emitted] [from: assets/icon-32.png] [copied]
  + 2 assets
assets by path *.js 41.8 MiB
  asset vendor.js 23.3 MiB [emitted] (name: vendor) 1 related asset
  asset taskpane.js 17.1 MiB [emitted] (name: taskpane) 1 related asset
  asset polyfill.js 1.17 MiB [emitted] (name: polyfill) 1 related asset
  asset commands.js 266 KiB [emitted] (name: commands) 1 related asset
assets by path *.html 2.26 KiB
  asset taskpane.html 1.81 KiB [emitted]
  asset commands.html 459 bytes [emitted]
asset manifest.xml 4.11 KiB [emitted] [from: manifest.xml] [copied]
4000 modules
webpack 5.89.0 compiled successfully in 25825 ms
```

What happens when you *"install"* the manifest? 
How can I check if it is properly installed?

Comment: you are using `MessageComposeCommandSurface` so this add-in will appear in Compose Mode mean in new mail ribbon

Comment: What are you doing to install the manifest?

If you run "npm run start" it should start the webpack server, sideload the add-in, and then open Outlook.  Are you using that command or another one?